# AS3 Using a list component and a MouseEvent listener

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, actionscript

```
var gulost:Object = new Object;
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, leggTilListe)

function leggTilListe(evt:MouseEvent)
{



gulost.navn = "Gulost";
gulost.kcal = Number(53) * numStepOst.value;
gulost.protein = Number(4) * numStepOst.value;
gulost.fett = Number(4.2) * numStepOst.value;
gulost.karbohydrater = Number(0) * numStepOst.value;
gulost.label = String(numStepOst.value) + " " + "skiver ost";

liste.addItem(gulost);
```

If the numeric stepper value is 2 then this will add " 2 skiver ost" to the list component. If i click the button again it will add another row of "2 skiver ost" beneath the previous one. How do I get these to stack instead of creating a seperate label?

// here is the full FLA file if someone need to take a closer look or don't understand what I mean :)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-U9O7J7V4bFQnpIMmhReE9yLTQ/view

Comment: first of all what do you mean by "stack"  ? you mean sum numerical value, append/prepend item (as suggested by the name of the method addItem) ? at each click you only create a new (untyped) object with new values (depending on the stepper value). it's the addItem that you should modify obviously but I don't know what its doing right now (post the code), neither what you precisely want it to do

Comment: The first click add the items to the list, but i want additional clicks to not create another item but add the additional values from the numeric stepper to the item added from the first click. I can post the full code but it's about 100 lines.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a local variable. It is visible only into a function. Try to initialize `gulost` outside.

```
var gulost:Object = new Object;
btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, leggTilListe)

function leggTilListe (e:MouseEvent) {
    //...Put your listener code here...
}
```

Comment: Yes I understand but it does not change anything with the application when I initialize it outside as a global variable.

Comment: Can you update your question message with these source changes?

Comment: If I understand you correctly it should be updated now.